# Need to know, why $apply need to be used

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to know, why we need to used $apply here,

```
var clock = angular.module('clock',[]); 
clock.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
        $scope.clock = new Date();
        var updateClock = function() {
          $scope.clock = new Date();
        };
        setInterval(function() {
          $scope.$apply(updateClock);
          //updateClock()  //why this will not work.
        }, 1000);
        updateClock();
      });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3gzN9/)

I know, when $apply is used :

> "The $apply() function executes an expression inside of the Angular
>   context from outside of the Angular framework. For instance, if we
>   implement a setTimeout() or are using a third-party library and we
>   want the event to run inside the Angular context, we must use
>   $apply()."
>   Blockquote

But why we need to use in this case (I mean in jsfiddle example), As I am in the same context and not using any jQuery code or third-party library,

[With Out $apply fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3gzN9/2/)

function is called, but the output is reflected in view, Why?

Comment: Because the angular devs chose to implement dirty-checking without polling. So the $rootScope.$digest() method does all the dirty checking and scope updating. In your example, nothing is calling $apply() or $digest() so no updates happen. Therefore, one must call $apply() because setTimeout does not automatically call $rootScope.$digest(). Hence the $timeout service as @Miraage has suggested.

Comment: There is also a $interval service.

Answer (score 1):

Read the following manual. :)
[https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply()](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-%24scope.%24apply%28%29)

// Upd from comments
You need to use [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24interval) service.

Comment: Or [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) since the OP is using `setInterval`

Comment: Exactly. I wanted to say, that he needs to use Angular services, instead of native.